# getting "No JSON object could be decoded" for json URL

Tags: python, json

The api returning json on brower but when parsing it on python I am getting this exception: `No JSON object could be decoded`. I have used both `json.load()` and `json.loads()` but failed.

**Here is that code.**

```
def handler_timeout(self):
        try:
            data = json.load(
                urlopen(
                    'https://www.zebapi.com/api/v1/market/ticker/btc/inr'
                )
            )
            buy_price = data['buy']
            sell_price = data['sell']
            status_message = "Buy: ₹ " + "{:,}".format(buy_price) + "   Sell: ₹ " + "{:,}".format(sell_price)
            self.ind.set_label(status_message, "")
        except Exception, e:
            print str(e)
            self.ind.set_label("!", "")
        return True
```

**Here is the output for `urlopen(URL)`:**

```
<addinfourl at 140336849031752 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x7fa2bb6f1cd0>>
```

**Here is the output for `urlopen(URL).read()` :**

```
��`I�%&/m�{J�J��t�`$ؐ@�������iG#)�*��eVe]f@�흼��{����{����;�N'���?\fdl��J�ɞ!���?~|?"~�o���G��~��=J�vv��;#�x���}��e���?=�N�u�/�h��ًWɧ�U�^���Ã���;���}�'���Q��ct
```

Comment: What is the output of ```urlopen(
                    'https://www.zebapi.com/api/v1/market/ticker/btc/inr'
                )```?

Comment: added in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of the url is [`gzip`-encoded](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html).

```
>>> u = urllib.urlopen('https://www.zebapi.com/api/v1/market/ticker/btc/inr')
>>> info = u.info()
>>> info['Content-Encoding']
'gzip'
```

Decompress the content.

```
import gzip
import io
import json
import urllib

u = urllib.urlopen('https://www.zebapi.com/api/v1/market/ticker/btc/inr')
with io.BytesIO(u.read()) as f:
    gz = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=f)
    print json.load(gz)
```

or use [`requests` which decode gzip automatically](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content):

```
import requests
print requests.get('https://www.zebapi.com/api/v1/market/ticker/btc/inr').json()
```